# IP Address list sorting

Tags: list, office-365, calculated-column

I have a list that contains IP address and im unable to sort on them.  I have a function that works in Excel

```
=VALUE(IF(NOT(ISBLANK((B3))),(LEFT((B3),FIND(".",(B3),1)-1)*16777216)+(MID((B3),FIND(".",(B3),1)+1,FIND(".",(B3),FIND(".",(B3),1)+1)-FIND(".",(B3),1)-1)*65536)+(MID((B3),FIND(".",(B3),FIND(".",(B3),1)+1)+1,FIND(".",(B3),FIND(".",(B3),FIND(".",(B3),1)+1)+1)-FIND(".",(B3),FIND(".",(B3),1)+1)-1)*256)+(RIGHT((B3),LEN((B3))-FIND(".",(B3),FIND(".",(B3),FIND(".",(B3),1)+1)+1))),0))
```

This works well.  My plan was to create a new column and use the calculation based on other column.  However, when I attempt to format this for O365 it errors on syntax.  Here is the function I am trying to use:

```
=VALUE(IF(NOT(ISBLANK([IP address]))),(LEFT([IP address]),FIND(".",[IP address]),1)-1)*16777216)+(MID([IP address]),FIND(".",[IP address]),1)+1,FIND(".",[IP address]),FIND(".",[IP address]),1)+1)-FIND(".",[IP address]),1)-1)*65536)+(MID([IP address]),FIND(".",[IP address]),FIND(".",[IP address]),1)+1)+1,FIND(".",[IP address]),FIND(".",[IP address]),FIND(".",[IP address]),1)+1)+1)-FIND(".",[IP address]),FIND(".",[IP address]),1)+1)-1)*256)+(RIGHT([IP address]),LEN([IP address]))-FIND(".",[IP address]),FIND(".",[IP address]),FIND(".",[IP address]),1)+1)+1))),0))
```

any ideas how else i can accomplish this differently, or help me find what i am missing would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

It is blowing up on the MID function, but not because it is not supported.
You are using **MID([IP address])** and only declared one parameter.

The MSDN link in the other answer indeed mentions the MID function is not supported,
but even Microsoft can produce incorrect documentation.

The [MID function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MID-function-2eba57be-0c05-4bdc-bf81-5ecf4421eb8a) is supported at least since SharePoint 2007.
see: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MID-function-2eba57be-0c05-4bdc-bf81-5ecf4421eb8a

#### All Functions that work in SharePoint:

https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

### calculate IP string

Your requirement is best solved by first detecting the 3 . (period) separators in the IP string.

**disclaimer**: Formulas below are to explain the concept; I have not checked if all calculations are correct.

Here's a screenshot of my ViewMaster365 CalcMaster Editor *(private use only, it can do way too much harm)*

[image]

#### Merging Columns

You can merge the C1,C2 en C3 columns
Blue strings are references to a previously declared Column.

[image]

#### All in one Calculated Column

As you can't copy/paste from a screenshot; your complete Formula in one Calculated Column is:

```
=VALUE(MID(IP,1,FIND(".",IP)-1))*16777216
+VALUE(MID(IP,FIND(".",IP)+1,FIND(".",IP)+FIND(".",MID(IP,FIND(".",IP)+1,99))-FIND(".",IP)-1))*65536
+VALUE(MID(IP,FIND(".",IP)+FIND(".",MID(IP,FIND(".",IP)+1,99))+1,FIND(".",IP)+FIND(".",MID(IP,FIND(".",IP)+1,99))+FIND(".",MID(IP,FIND(".",IP)+FIND(".",MID(IP,FIND(".",IP)+1,99))+1,99))-FIND(".",IP)+FIND(".",MID(IP,FIND(".",IP)+1,99))-1))*256
+VALUE(MID(IP,FIND(".",IP)+FIND(".",MID(IP,FIND(".",IP)+1,99))+FIND(".",MID(IP,FIND(".",IP)+FIND(".",MID(IP,FIND(".",IP)+1,99))+1,99))+1,99))
```

ICC

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is blowing up on the `MID` expression, it isn't supported.

> Note Microsoft SharePoint Foundation formulas for calculated fields
>   are based on Microsoft Excel functions and syntax. However, Microsoft
>   supports only those functions mentioned on this page for use in
>   SharePoint Foundation calculated fields. For example, the Excel
>   function MID is not supported.

- [Calculated Field Formulas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: Hmm ok.  can you think of any other way to accomplish this.  i have multiple subnets and the current sorting in sharepoint makes it difficult to see the used IP address. i have currently
10.2/16
10.3/16
10.20/16
10.80/16
10.100/16
10.102/16
which is making it very difficult to find whats open and whats not

Comment: i have also noticed that Substring is also not available,  that would have also worked... kinda.

Comment: Not knowing what your list looks like, I can only suggest breaking out the 4 octets into their own columns, then creating a calculated column off of those 4. It'll at least make it a bit easier to read the formulas and tweak them.